# Как передать через CMD в docker командную строку Python?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Мне нужно сконструировать Dockerfile таким образом, чтобы при компиле моего контейнера завелась командная строчка типа python app.py --name smth -- works somth.
Я новичок в docker и не совсем разбираюсь в этой теме, так что заранее спасибо!

Comment: Под словом "завелась" вы понимаете выполнение скрипта app.py с указанными вами параметрами при старте вашего контейнера ?

Comment: Да, я это имел в виду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) или [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) директивы в Dockerfile или одноименные опции в [docker-compose.yml](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) файле.